# Как разбить динамический массив на два массива без изменения и сдвигов его данных в памяти?

Tags: c

Есть динамический массив из 10 чисел. Как откусить от этого массива любое количество элементов так, чтобы их стал содержать другой динамический массив, и так, чтобы расположение исходных чисел в памяти осталось неизменным (без копирования и сдвигов памяти)?

Я хочу узнать, можно ли в принципе такое делать с исходным массивом: откусывать порцию его памяти от его конца или, наоборот, начиная с его начала.

```
int *numbers = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
int *numbers2;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    numbers[i] = i + 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("el: %d\n", numbers[i]);
}

// что сделать с numbers и numbers2, чтобы, например, в numbers остались элементы с 1го по 9ый, а 10ый элемент оказался в numbers2?
```

P.S. Естественно дело не в числах типа int, я просто их тут взял для примера.

Спасибо.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, IMHO  в принципе никак. По крайней мере с текущей версией eglibc-2.11

Comment: @avp, я предполагал такой ответ, и поэтому спрошу: хорошо, а если с копированием, то какой вариант будет наиболее быстрый? (предположим только, что у меня 1000 элементов из которых я хочу вырезать 5)? memcpy + realloc?

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Stanislaw Pankevich](/users/10139/stanislaw-pankevich)](/users/10139/stanislaw-pankevich), если уменьшаем (оставляя начало), то безусловно realloc быстрее. Если начальный адрес не изменяется, то намного быстрее.

Изменится он или нет при отрезании хвоста -- сложный вопрос (исходники malloc в eglibc это 12000(!) строк исходника. Думаю тривиальную реализацию можно уложить в пару сотен строк), но в любом случае это не медленнее malloc+memcpy.

А вот всегда ли нужно отрезать хвост -- это вопрос. Т.к. может вырасти фрагментация памяти кусочками, которые замедлят работу malloc/realloc.

Заранее тут однозначно ничего не скажешь. Очень много факторов.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *numbers = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    int *numbers2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        numbers[i] = i + 1;
    }
    numbers2 = &numbers[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("el: %d\n", numbers2[i]);
    }
}
```

Этот код выведет

> el: 8
> el: 9
> el: 10

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я в курсе, что так сделать можно. Но что будет с numbers2, если я сделаю free(numbers)? Я хочу реальное разбиение.

Comment: Не знаю, то ли это, что вы хотели. И если то, не думаю, что это удачный способ использовать возможности Си. С этим языком можно очень и очень сильно начудить при работе с памятью...

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich - если Вам нужно "реальное разбиение", тогда Вам нужно делать свой менеджер памяти. По поверьте, на размерах в десяток элементов malloc + memcpy будет достаточно быстрым.

Comment: Я так и думал, но задал вопрос, чтобы собрать подтверждения. Спасибо.